# Sorting array to avoid repeating consecutive values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following array

```
$categories = array("first",
"first",
"first",
"first",
"second",
"second",
"second",
"second",
"second",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"third",
"four",
"four",
"four",
"five",
"five",
"five",
"six",
"six",
"seven");
```

What I want to do is sort above array **so that the same category is not coming one after another in a row.** i.e. array should be sorted like

```
array("first","second","third","four","five","six","seven","first","second","third"........)
```

I know this can be achieved via PHP's `uasort()` function. But i am  having trouble thinking of make a comparison function.

Also the possible way i could do is chunking each category into separate arrays and looping through each array to create the resulting array, but I m  not sure whether it is efficient way or not.

Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: those aren't unique values.  in your desired results.

Comment: That sort order doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. Can you describe the desired behaviour other than "by unique"?

Comment: So, basically you want to create unique value buckets and then build arrays out of those buckets until they're all empty?

Comment: so... i think i know what you want.  and you can do that but somewhere you will need to actually define that `"one"=1`.  and then sort on the integer value.  also... i'm gonna guess... [that your name is the devil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBecM3CQVD8) but i could be wrong.

Comment: **unique:** `being the only one of its kind; unlike anything else.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
$buckets = array_count_values($categories);

$results = array();

while (array_sum($buckets) > 0) {
    foreach ($buckets as $index => $value) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $results[] = $index;
            $buckets[$index] = $value - 1;
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

It breaks down the array into unique values and their respective frequency, then iterates each value and pushes them into the final array until all values have been consumed.

#### Results

```
Array
(
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
    [2] => third
    [3] => four
    [4] => five
    [5] => six
    [6] => seven
    [7] => first
    [8] => second
    [9] => third
    [10] => four
    [11] => five
    [12] => six
    [13] => first
    [14] => second
    [15] => third
    [16] => four
    [17] => five
    [18] => first
    [19] => second
    [20] => third
    [21] => second
    [22] => third
    [23] => third
    [24] => third
    [25] => third
)
```

Then, the trailing values need to be reinserted into the final result so that there are no repeats ... reader's exercise :)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, its almost what I needed. but at last the category  "third" is repeated 4 times in a row. I think I will manage to address this issue.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to rearrange the trailing values so that the end result has no repeating values ...

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for this, I've created a working prototype of this algorithm.

Here is the flowchart:

[image: random sort without consecutive repeats]

Python implementation:

```py
import random

def randomize_list(input_list):
    randomized_list = input_list.copy()
    random.shuffle(randomized_list)
    return randomized_list


def get_repeated_items(input_list, type_key):
    repeated_items = []
    pre_sorted_list = []
    last_item = {}
    for item in input_list:
        if last_item and item[type_key] == last_item[type_key]:
            repeated_items.append(item)
            continue
        pre_sorted_list.append(item)
        last_item = item
    return repeated_items, pre_sorted_list

def recycle_repeated_items(repeated_items, pre_sorted_list, type_key):
    sorted_list = []
    last_item = {}
    changed = False
    for item in pre_sorted_list:
        filtered_types = [item[type_key]] + ([last_item[type_key]] if last_item else [])
        eligible_repeated_item = next(filter(lambda t: t[type_key] not in filtered_types, repeated_items), None)
        if eligible_repeated_item:
            changed = True
            repeated_items.remove(eligible_repeated_item)
            sorted_list.append(eligible_repeated_item)
        sorted_list.append(item)
        last_item = item
    return repeated_items, sorted_list, changed

def randomized_non_repeating_sort(input_list, type_key):
    randomized_list = randomize_list(input_list)
    repeated_items, sorted_list = get_repeated_items(randomized_list, type_key)
    repeated_items, sorted_list, changed = recycle_repeated_items(repeated_items, sorted_list, type_key)
    while repeated_items and changed:
        repeated_items, sorted_list, changed = recycle_repeated_items(repeated_items, sorted_list, type_key)
    return sorted_list + repeated_items
```

Example usage:

```py
original_list = [
    {'id': 10, 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 11, 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 12, 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 13, 'type': 'A'},
    {'id': 14, 'type': 'B'},
    {'id': 15, 'type': 'B'},
    {'id': 16, 'type': 'B'},
    {'id': 17, 'type': 'C'},
    {'id': 18, 'type': 'C'},
    {'id': 19, 'type': 'D'}
]

print('Original list:')
print(original_list)

print('Randomized non-repeating list (1 of 1,000,000 tests):')

for _ in range(1,1000000):
    output_list = randomized_non_repeating_sort(original_list, 'type')
    repeated_items = get_repeated_items(output_list, 'type')[0]
    if repeated_items:
        raise Exception('CONSECUTIVE REPEATED ITEM FOUND!')
    if len(output_list) != len(original_list):
        raise Exception('LIST LENGTH MISMATCH!')

print(output_list)

"""
Output:
[{'id': 15, 'type': 'B'},
 {'id': 10, 'type': 'A'},
 {'id': 17, 'type': 'C'},
 {'id': 12, 'type': 'A'},
 {'id': 19, 'type': 'D'},
 {'id': 13, 'type': 'A'},
 {'id': 18, 'type': 'C'},
 {'id': 16, 'type': 'B'},
 {'id': 11, 'type': 'A'},
 {'id': 14, 'type': 'B'}]
"""
```

I have also written a blog post with more details on this algorithm: https://tomaraei.com/random-sort-algorithm-without-consecutive-repeats/